# github heroku master branch

Tags: git, heroku

I am a newbie to Github except a few tutorial projects created in Github using Git Bash CLI. 
I downloaded a Github zip archive of a Heroku getting-started app and in my local I make some changes and I pushed that new app in to Heroku under my name as a new app. How would I keep a remote repo on Github ? I guess the push to heroku is just a deployment and its not the code repository? I dont want to loose my changes when the local hard drive crash;

This is my simple workflow:
download Github Archive of Getting Started Heroku app ------> changed the app to my requirements and named it myNewApp ----------> create a heroku account and push the code ----> ???next to keep a remote repo ????

Appreciate any help.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote --verbose` will list all of repository remotes.
In your situation I guess it is a heroku repository on github.

I suggest to create a fork (at github) of Getting Started Heroku app and than clone it to your development machine so `origin` remote will be yours.
Ref: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

If you already made some changes on cloned heroku repo you could create an empty github repo and than add a new remote

```
git remote add github remote repository URL
# Sets the new remote
git remote --verbose
# Verifies the new remote URL
git push github
# Push your changes to yours github repo
```

Comment: 1.> I forked the heroku get-started-app to my git repo.
2.> Cloned to local:

Comment: I fork the heroku getting started App to my Github repo. And clone the project to my local and after making changes, push to github 

<local drive>\myNewApp>git push github
Counting objects: 459, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (355/355), done.
Writing objects: 100% (459/459), 225.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 459 (delta 76), reused 450 (delta 70)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (76/76), done.
To https://github.com/[userName]/myNewApp.git
   6c39053..23ffae9  master -> master
In github I dont see the changes yet... Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Sansun did you commit your changes before push? Please do some git tutorials (e.g. https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1). It is always helpful ;)

Comment: Thank you. Once I type 'git . add'  and then 'git commit'  'git push' does the trick.